# delay() problem for 74HC595 and 7-segment

Tags: 7-segment

I'm trying to run a 3-digit 7-segment using single 74HC595 based on Arduino. But I have a serious problem with `delay()` function. When I want to count from 000 to 999 with `delay(1000)`, this delay function causes all digits to be off! My code is as below and I uploaded a video **[Click Here](http://s12.picofile.com/file/8400330784/VID_20200617_212526.mp4.html)** to understand my purpose. This problem can affect some applications like reading the temperature of DS12b20 which requires a delay itself.

```
//                 2        1         0       
//               ----      ----      ----    
//              |    |    |    |    |    |
//               ----      ----      ----
//              |    |    |    |    |    |
//               ----      ----      ----

int latch = 8; //74HC595  pin STCP
int clock = 9; //74HC595  pin SHCP
int data = 10; //74HC595  pin DS

// Each annode pin (for those that don't know think of it as an on switch when it's assigned HIGH)
int dig1 = 2; // digit0
int dig2 = 3; // digit1
int dig3 = 4; // digit2
int digit[4]={dig1, dig2, dig3};

int timer=3;
// these are bits to make the 8 bit byte accepted by the segment display the 9th is the demical point
// 0-9 then invald numbers
byte table[] = {
  B00111111, B00000110, B01011011, B01001111, B01100110,
  B01101101, B01111101, B00000111, B01111111, B01101111, B01111111
};

void setup(){
  pinMode(latch, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(data, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dig1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dig2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dig3, OUTPUT);
}

//this sends the data to the digit
void RunNum(int num, int SelectDigit){
  digitalWrite(latch, LOW);
  shiftOut(data, clock, MSBFIRST, table[num]);
  digitalWrite(latch, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(digit[SelectDigit], LOW);
  delay(timer);
  digitalWrite(digit[SelectDigit], HIGH);
  
}


//main program
void loop() {
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
      for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
        RunNum(k, 0);
        RunNum(j, 1);
        RunNum(i, 2);
        delay(1000);  //  <====    This line affects the project
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I updated my code (only `void loop()`) as below using `millis()`. You can watch the results (**[Click Here](http://s12.picofile.com/file/8400414976/VID_20200618_195832.mp4.html)**). But, the delay problem has not been solved so far!

```
const long interval = 1000;   //  1000 ms = 1 s
long previousMillis = 0; 
unsigned long currentMillis=0;

//main program
void loop() {
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
      for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
        while (currentMillis - previousMillis < interval){
          currentMillis=millis();
          RunNum(k, 0);
          RunNum(j, 1);
          RunNum(i, 2);
        }
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So then don't use `delay()`. To do timed things, you need to learn a non-blocking coding style, like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example via the `millis()`. Look a the example and at tutorials about millis(). When you fully understand them, you will be able to replace the delay with non-blocking code

Comment: Thanks @chrisl. I already used of `millis` function. But it's useful for digital counting only like for making a digital clock. It's too bad for other applications like for DS18b20 temperature.

Comment: @soheil What are you talking about? I don't see, why `millis()`should be too bad to use here. `delay()` also just uses `millis()`in the background. And I also don't see how it should affect the temperature measurement. It is absolutely the way to go for handling the 1s delay there.

Comment: @chrisl This is a good question. Suppose that you have a DS18B20 temperature sensor. The sensor response time is about 0.5 sec (may be up to 0.75 sec). If you want to display it using 74HC595, during this time (exactly like a delay) the 7-segments are turned off! and after that they are turned on to display temperature. This appears like a flash (carefully watch the uploaded video). Some chips like MAX7219 doesn't interrupt the output when they don't have input (they run previous commands) while it seems that 74HC595 continuously needs the commands to keep the its output active.

Comment: @soheil So your problem is with the temperature sensor. Then you need to show a code, that really uses your temperature sensor. Currently you are asking about the 1s delay, for which Juraj provided a fitting answer. We can only understand how that might collude with the temp sensor, when we see the temp sensor code.

Comment: The 74HC595 doesn't need constant commands. If you stop shifting data out to it, it will keep the current state of the outputs. Though since you are reusing the same pins of it for all three digits, you need to constantly provide fitting data for each digit. That is not a property of the shift register, but of your circuit, which forms a matrix

Comment: If the 74HC595 sensor library you're using has delay() functions in it of more than a few milliseconds, you're going to have to modify your library function that reads the temp sensor to be non-blocking. (by following the model of blinkWithoutDelay.)

Comment: Either that or you are going to need to rewire your display to latch all 3 digits at once, and keep the whole display lit at once, or use a display driver that can multiplex all 3 digits automatically for you. You could use a MAX7221 for example. You'd feed the digits you need it to display using a serial interface, then read a new value from your temp sensor and feed the new value to the display driver. The display driver would continue to display the old value until the new value was sent.

Comment: @chrisl Thank you so much. But the temperature sensor is just one example which requires delay. Delay in my code simulates the raised problem of such usages. I can just say that **how to avoid flashing in displaying numbers in such applications?**

Comment: @chrisl Exactly. I think that one of the reasons is that in my code: first it should active the first digit and display its number and then inactive it and active the second digit and display its number and then inactive it and so on. This process should continuously be done to show all numbers without flashing. But, any delay (may be more than 20 ms) stops this process (of course for our eyes) and causes flashing in display. How do you think?

Comment: Thanks @Duncan-C. The delay is for sending and receiving data and can be up to 750 ms. MAX7219 and MAX7221 are great. Your idea is rewiring. How?

Comment: Remove the 74HC595 from your project and replace it with a Max7221 instead. The 7221 is able to drive up to 8 7-segment characters (plus decimals, for a total of 8 segments per character.) It is driven with a serial interface, so you send it commands to display values. A quick Google search reveals Arduino libraries for using it.

Answer (score 3):

With the displays which use shift register to light multiple seven segment digit blocks, the register lights up only one digit at a time. The illusion of multiple digits lit is created by fast switching the digits in round. Small delays in this cause the number to look dim, larger delays create flickering and long delays show only one digit lit. So a sketch handling this type of display must run without delays.

In this type of sketch, everything must be handled without delays, so if some sensor requires a delay, start the reading and a millis timer and after the elapsed time read the result.

There are displays using specialized chips, for example TM1637D, which handle the seven segments even if your sketch stops in delay.

---

adoption of the [BlinkWithoutDelay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) basic example for your algorithm:

```
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 1000;
int i, j, k;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    k++;
    if ( k == 10) {
      k = 0;
      j++;
      if (j == 10) {
        j = 0;
        i++;
        if (i == 10) {
          i = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(j);
    Serial.println(k);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But **this isn't the correct answer!** I already tried it. Please, carefully read the question.

Comment: Just a note, there is no temperature sensor or library included for one in the code presented.  For the question as presented this is the correct answer.  If there is some problem where your temperature sensor takes too long to read then that is a separate issue.  That's not the same as having a delay in your code.  Instead of trying to code around that time, fix the library for the sensor so it doesn't take so long.

Comment: `delay()` just simulates the required delay of such sensors. In real applications, this delay causes the flashing in display.

Comment: @soheil, I enhanced the answer

Comment: Thank you. I think changing chip is the best idea. I even used of two 74HC595 combined with ULN2803. But its result became worst. In fact, some segments of an inactive digit were a little bright!!!!!! 74HC595 can't handle the `delay()`.

Comment: The use of `millis()` is suitable for digital clock, timer, ...

Comment: @soheil, with millis we do timed events. see this sketch https://github.com/jandrassy/lab/blob/master/KitchenTimer/KitchenTimer.ino

Comment: I updated your code based on `millis()`.

Comment: @soheil, that code was wrong. you can't embed the timer inside 3 `for` loops. the main loop must run

Comment: I ran that and it worked fine. No problem.

Comment: @soheil, if that is all what your sketch should do, then it is ok

Answer (score 1):

<strike>In `loop()` as you've shown it in your code, you can move `RunNum(i,2);` down to outside of the 'j' and 'k' loops. Likewise you can move `RunNum(j,1);` down to outside of the 'k' loop. This won't fix your problem but it will speed up each update of the display.</strike>

Then, know that you can tell one (or all) of your DS18B20 sensors to start a temperature conversion *without waiting for the conversion to finish*. Then you use millis() to tell you when the conversion is done, and you can get the result very quickly. Some libraries provide the amount of time you need to wait for the conversion; some provide some kind of an "is it done yet?" boolean function. Either one of those will let you remove the 'wait til done' delay.

Update:

> This strategy doesn't work properly!...

Sorry if I missed something - it looked like there were opportunities to optimize there.

> About temperature sensor, I should say that reading the temperature takes about 750 ms itself. In other words, it acts as a delay and causes turning off the display for 750 ms.

It is temperature measurement and conversion to a 12-bit result - which takes place *entirely within the DS18B20* sensor itself - that takes 750ms. *The Arduino is not involved in that process* and could be doing other tasks such as maintaining your display during that time.

*Reading* the temperatures, once the conversion is done, is much quicker.  If your library doesn't provide the ability to start a conversion and return, without waiting for the results, and separate entry to read the results, look for a library that does.

Update:
[Miles Burton's Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library](https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library) provides a 'wait for conversion' flag that you can set false so ::requestsTemperatures() will return immediately, and an ::isConversionComplete() call to check whether the data is ready. (Of course, knowing that the device takes 750ms
for a 12-bit conversion, you could just as well use millis() to decide that.)

Comment: Thank you. This strategy doesn't work properly! because if you do that, digits 1 and 2 are turned off until digit 0 counts from 0 to 9. Then digit 1 quickly displays number 1 and is turned off and again digit 0 counts from 0 to 9 and so on.

Comment: About temperature sensor, I should say that reading the temperature takes about 750 ms itself. In other words, it acts as a delay and causes turning off the display for 750 ms. As another example, suppose that you need to call a php script using ESP8266 D1 Mini (it can similarly be programmed using Arduino IDE) and then display some returned numbers using 74HC595. Calling a php script may take over 15 s and during this time all digits are turned off.